# How to remove tax from cart page?

Tags: cart, tax

I am looking to completely remove any tax calculation from the cart page.  I would like tax calculation to only happen at the end of the process on the final checkout page.  I have looked at the .phtml files in `/template/cart/totals.phtml` but haven't found a way to edit them to remove the tax.  Ideally I would like the totals to read as following

> Product Order: $xxx 
>  Shipping & Handling: $xx
>  sub-total:
>   $xxx

So instead of a "grand total" at the end there is just a sub-total of everything except tax.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If I understand you correctly you want show taxes only on the checkout page. 
To do that you have to change settings in the same section as author of previous answer has stated - just alot more options as you have to change whole calculation process.

Go to Configuration > Sales Section > Tax

1. *Tax Calculation Method Based On: Totals*
2. *Display Shipping Prices: Excluding Tax*
3. *Display Subtotal: Excluding Tax*
4. *Display Shipping Amount: Excluding Tax*
5. *Include Tax In Grand Total: No*
6. *Display full tax summary: No - Don't display specific tax values for specific rates. Don't let users expand tax to see what made the grand tax in separated values [i.e. tax for shipping, tax for products 21%].*
7. *Display Zero Tax Subtotal - No - If there's a 0 tax value should users see it anyway on subtotal summary?*

Additionaly It may require changing template files in:

`app/design/theme/package/tax/checkout/subtotal.phtml`
`app/design/theme/package/tax/checkout/grandtotal.phtml`
`app/design/theme/package/tax/checkout/tax.phtml`

Answer (score 4):

Just found this answer on another thread of the site: it works perfectly.

Under `{magento_base}/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/tax/checkout/`

Edit file `grandtotal.phtml` 
(I suggest you make a backup of the file just in case).

Find the line:

includeTax() && $this->getTotalExclTax()>=0):?>

Delete the subsequent lines:

```
<tr>
    <td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right" colspan="<?php echo $this->getColspan(); ?>">
        <strong><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Grand Total Excl. Tax')?></strong>
    </td>
    <td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right">
        <strong><?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getTotalExclTax()) ?></strong>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This takes care of the grand total part.

For tax,

Check [this link:](http://www.rvndesign.com/hide-tax-detail-from-cart-checkout-page-in-magento/%20Clear%20the%20cache%20and%20you're%20set.)

Comment: Don't make a copy, but instead copy it to your own theme!

Answer (score 2):

The totals are displayed automatically from certain rows in the quote and the file that does so also does that for other pages.

Now we could come up with some fancy technical solution but in your case I would try to fix it with CSS.

Since you just want some cosmetic change just hide the tax and grandtotal row with something like `display:none` and you're done

Answer (score 1):

you can managed this settign from admin

Go to `admin>System>Configuration>Sales>Tax>Shopping Cart Display Settings`

make `Display Subtotal=Excluding Tax`

[image]

**you can managed tax display setting on cart page,from here admin>System>Configuration>Sales>Tax>Shopping Cart Display Setting**

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have that Set, yet the tax still shows on the cart page when a customer enters their zip / state for shipping

Comment: it was my silly  mistake,now check again

Comment: Yes, I have that set aswell.  It seems to have no effect..cleared cache and reindexed

Comment: Yes that is for the subtotal, however I need the tax to not show up at all and not be calculated in the "Grand Total"

Comment: In my configuration i set excluding tax, still tax calculated. Actually i don't want calculate tax on my order

Answer (score 1):

1.To Disable the tax row go to your theme > Magento_Tax/layout/checkout_index_index.xml and checkout_cart_index.xml then add the lines:

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="tax" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
 </referenceBlock>
```

Disabling an item using this way only hides it from view but still loaded in the query. If you want to completely remove it from page load then follow the documentation stated in the above link.

[Remove label and value Tax from cart magento 2.1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/145910/remove-label-and-value-tax-from-cart-magento-2-1)

Comment: It helps if Shopping Cart Display Settings are not working for some reason