# Remove Tax calculation from cart page and calculate only in checkout

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to remove tax calculation from cart page. And need to only calculate tax when in checkout.

Example : 
Cart Page (After stop all the tax calculations and tax displaying)
Sub Total : $300
Grand Total : $300

Checkout Page - (assuem tax rate is 10 %)
Sub Total : $300
Tax : $10
Grand Total : $330

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want show taxes only on the checkout page. 
To do that you have to change settings in the same section.

Go to Configuration > Sales Section > Tax

1. Tax Calculation Method Based On: Totals
2. Display Shipping Prices: Excluding Tax
3. Display Subtotal: Excluding Tax
4. Display Shipping Amount: Excluding Tax
5. Include Tax In Grand Total: No
6. Display full tax summary: No - Don't display specific tax values for specific rates. Don't let users expand tax to see what made the grand tax in separated values [i.e. tax for shipping, tax for products 21%].
7. Display Zero Tax Subtotal - No - If there's a 0 tax value should users see it anyway on subtotal summary?

Additionaly It may require changing template files in:

`app/design/theme/package/tax/checkout/subtotal.phtml`
`app/design/theme/package/tax/checkout/grandtotal.phtml`
`app/design/theme/package/tax/checkout/tax.phtml`

[For More See here.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31603/how-to-remove-tax-from-cart-page)